# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Can't solve problems with test Spring Boot application:**

```
spring.bat init --artifactId=dbproto3 --boot-version=2.1.7.RELEASE --dependencies=jdbc,data-rest,web,thymeleaf,devtools,lombok,configuration-processor,security,data-jpa,data-jdbc,postgresql,actuator --description=dbproto3 --groupId=com.test --java-version=11 --name=dbproto3 --package-name=com.test.dbproto3 --version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

It is a test application made by modifying **Guide "Accessing data with MySQL"** from official Spring site. The first version (close to initial: empty springconfig, @Controller and @RequestMapping(path="/demo"), ...) worked great but my version generates an exception

**Running it i get an exception:**

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  2 .   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  3 .   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  4 .   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  5 .   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  6 .   at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
  7 . Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.dbproto3.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
  8 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
  9 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
 10 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
 11 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
 12 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
 13 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
 14 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
 15 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 16 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
 17 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 18 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
 19 .   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
 20 .   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
 21 .   at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
 22 .   at com.test.dbproto3.Dbproto3Application.main(Dbproto3Application.java:18)
 23 .   ... 5 more
 24 . Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.dbproto3.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
 25 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658)
 26 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217)
 27 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
 28 .   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
 29 .   ... 19 more
```

**Dbproto3Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
  2 . public class Dbproto3Application {
  3 .
  4 .    public static void main(String[] args) {
  5 .         SpringApplication.run(Dbproto3Application.class, args);
  6 .
  7 .         ApplicationContext javaConfigContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
  8 .
  9 .         MainController mainControllerObj = (MainController) javaConfigContext.getBean("mainController");
 10 .
 11 .         mainControllerObj.addNewUser();
 12 .    }
 13 . }
```

**SpringConfig:**

```
  1 . @Configuration
  2 . public class SpringConfig {
  3 .     @Bean("mainController")
  4 .     public MainController createMainController() {
  5 .         return new MainController();
  6 .     }
  7 . }
```

**User:**

```
 1 . @Entity
  2 . @Table(name = "userstab")
  3 . public class User {
  4 .   @Id
  5 .   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  6 .   private Integer id;
  7 .
  8 .   private String name;
  9 .
 10 .   private String email;
 11 .
 12 . }
```

**UserRepository:**

```
  1 . public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
  2 .
  3 . }
```

**MainController:**

```
  3 . public class MainController {
  4 .
  5 .     @Autowired
  6 .     private UserRepository userRepository;
  7 .
  8 .
  9 .     public void addNewUser() {
 10 .         User n = new User();
 11 .         n.setName("testuser");
 12 .         n.setEmail("testemail");
 13 .         System.out.println("addNewUser()");
 14 .         userRepository.save(n);
 15 .     }
 16 .
 17 . }
```

**application properties:**

```
server.port = 8082

## default connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5


## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example_db
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=123456

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not see any annotations for your repository interface in the code that you shared .Even though you are extending the `CrudRepository` interface to create your own interface. Spring boot needs to understand during startup that it needs to provide default implementation for your entities.Use annotation `@Repository` on your interface like :

```
 @Repository
 public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
  
  }
```

Also, you are creating the controller bean in some weird way , so you might be attempting something unconventional which means just using `@Autowired` in your main application class might also be a bit of stretch for you. But i would suggest doing that. You are using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to  create the bean for your controller but you are only providing the configuration class that you created for scanning. Maybe the bean for UserRepository since it's getting created by springboot is not present in the application context that you created using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. I think it's a standalone context.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql - this is the initial guide. Spring Data automatically generates CRUD implementation without `@Repository`. Adding  `@Repository` changes nothing

Comment: @asdfgh apparently that is not happening for you so that is why i asked you to add the annotation . Probably because of your directory structure or where you have placed you main application class. Springboot normally checks for bean creation taking the package where main application resides as the root.

Comment: I don't use a `@Controller` because i need to use Repository in a custom bean, which is not a controller. But i can't understand why **changing annotated-configurated class to java-configurated brakes `@Autowired `**

Comment: All classes are in the same directory

Comment: If i delete @Autowired, Spring Boot creates mainController bean without problems, i can get it via getBean() and call addNewUser().

Comment: if i use `@Controller` instead of java-configuration Spring Boot injectes  a userRepository without any problems and i can add new entry in userstab table using MainController.

Comment: May be the problem is in the order of bean inialization? May be Repository is initialized after MainController?

Comment: @asdfgh Oh it just occured to that cince you are creating the bean for the controller using annotatedapplicationcontext which is a standalone application context as per my knowledge , maybe the user repository  bean is not present in it as it is created by spring. Try manually creating user repository bean as well via the configuration class once to verify or set base packages to scan so that the user repository bean is aso created.